# same page anchor Still Not Working on mobile devices

Tags: html, iphone, ipad, hyperlink, anchor

Ok so i've been searching for an answer to this for a while and althought there are lots of queries along the same lines, none of them are solving my problem.

Using the following code, I am trying to link a button to a section further down the page..

```
<a href="#tour" class="input"><img src="assets/images/seetheapp.png" alt="Download the App" width="300" height="48" style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></a>
```

calling it using..

```
<a id="tour"></a>
```

works fine on desktop but not at all on iPhone (even pop up options not working) and only works on iPad in landscape mode... i'm completely stumped!

It is currently live (pulsatedate.com) so need to get it sorted asap.

Comment: Are you using html5 or html4? if html4 then you can try adding the `name` attribute: `<a id="tour" name="tour"></a>` otherwise try putting the id onto a div or other element

Comment: It's so weird it's not working.. anyways I tried <a href="#page-twitter" class="input">img</a> and it seems to work. I think it's because the #tour anchor is empty. You can try add a empty pixel or &nbsp;

Comment: @msbodetti linking to #page-twitter will do in this case! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Linking to the existing section/div id rather than an anchor has been a suitable work around in this instance.

```
<a href="#page-twitter" class="input"><img src="assets/images/seetheapp.png" alt="Download the App" width="300" height="48" style="margin-bottom: 100px;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at the `<head>` tag and find maybe some file override and disable anchoring I had this case:

forgot about disabling `jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js` because I had used before replacing to other framework and forgot to delete or comment

Answer (score 0):

With some jquery, when clicking on the anchor element hide or remove your active class

here is sample code,

```
<header class="header-section">
  <ul class="main-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#home" class="js-hide-header">
            &nbsp;Home
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#about" class="js-hide-header">
            &nbsp;About
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#service" class="js-hide-header">
            &nbsp;Services
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#contact" class="js-hide-header">
            &nbsp;Contact
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

inside .js file

```
$(".js-hide-header").on('click', function(e) {
    $('.header-section').removeClass('active');
});
```